# how to remove uploaded files from a folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, file-upload

My project has a feature for uploading files. The uploaded files are saved in a folder named "My Files". I have some web control  that I can use to remove or add the files. I can remove files with the control but not those that have been uploaded  to "My Files" folder. how can I do it?
Here is my code for adding file to "My Files" folder:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyArray.Length; i++){
    fileName = Request.QueryString["ID"] + "_" + valesArray[i];
    Request.Files["ctrl-" + i  ].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("") + "\\MyFiles\\" + fileName);
    MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Upld_" + i, "MyFiles/" + fileName);
}
```

Comment: is name of your folder  "My Files" or "MyFiles"?

Comment: @dllhell: MyFile. what a careful man !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that remove means delete, try this:

```
using System.IO;
File.Delete ( string.Format ( @"{0}\{1}",  Server.MapPath ( "MyFiles" ), fileName ) );
```